# For each loop for a past quiz

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, tostring

So the question is " I have a collection class object called inventory , and it contains objects form a class called Items. Suppose the Items class contains a toString() method to make printing easy. Write a for-each loop that will iterate over the entire collection class, and, for each object in the class, prints the object to System.out."

I have -

```
for(String items: inventory){
toString += items.toString();
System.out.print(items)
```

Is that correct?

Comment: i assume this is homework and java.  If not please correct the tags I added.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is java, and also that it's homework.

Not correct.

If the collection contains `Items` instances, as you wrote (the class should probably be called `Item`, not `Items`), then the loop should be declared like

```
for(Items item: inventory){
   ...
}
```

You are not closing your for loop in the code in your example. Also, if you just need to print everything in your list, you dont need `+=` (string concatenation). You can just print the item directly, each time thru the loop.

`System.out.println(item.toString());`

Comment: So are you saying that I don't need the middle part at all I can just write   
    for(Items items: inventory){
     System.out.println(item.toString());
     }
?

Comment: Something like that, yes.  Why don't u try it

Comment: Well I don't actually have a collection class for Items so it won't compile.

Comment: Actually writing some java code using loops might be a good way to get a hang of this. It may also help you in remembering the syntax, rather than just trying to memorize it with nothing to attach the memory to.

Comment: @jordan you do have a collection class. Many in fact.  Look at the documentation, at all the List and Set and Map implementations...

Answer (score 1):

You are now calling `toString` on a `String` object which is not intended and the description says that `inventory` contains objects of the class `Items`. It should more likely be as follows:

```
String result;
for (Items items : inventory) {
    result += items.toString();
}
System.out.print(result);
```

Comment: That's true, but at this early stage I'd rather give the answer :-) Well, I just realized that if `items.toString()` does not end with a newline, there's still some editing for him to do.

Comment: Ok thanks I appreciate it. Also I'm not actually typing this out I am just studying for a final, and this was a question on a quiz that I missed earlier in the term.